# clinfo is not detecting intel GPU

Tags: gpu, opencl, intel

`clinfo` detects CPU and one other device but it does not detect intel GPU.

```
(py36) root@933ec02aa577:/home/user# clinfo -l
Platform #0: Intel(R) OpenCL
 `-- Device #0: Genuine Intel(R) CPU $0000%@
Platform #1: Intel(R) FPGA Emulation Platform for OpenCL(TM)
 `-- Device #0: Intel(R) FPGA Emulation Device
(py36) root@933ec02aa577:/home/user#
```

I have added user to `video` group, installed drivers mentioned here but still not able to detect Intel GPU https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.html

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

[Edit - Thank to Peter Cordes for pointing out, correcting my answer]

Able to resolve the this. Apparently root cause was incorrect drivers were installed. Reinstalling drivers fixed this issues.

As Peter Cordes, pointing out in comments. I verified that `root` user do not need to be added in `video` or `render` group. It is required if you are running as a non `root` user.

Comment: Even though you're running `clinfo` as root?  That's odd, but running stuff as root is generally not what you want to do long-term anyway.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. You were right, i verified that `root` do not need to be added in video/render group. apparently reinstalling drivers is what fixed the issue. I corrected my answer.